# batch update a column using sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a database table (db2) with a very large number of rows (a couple million). I need to change the datatype of one of the columns.

In DB2 LUW there does not seem to be a way to directly change the datatype of a column (ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE does not work). So I am creating a new column, copying data to it and dropping the old column.

Since its not a good idea to do a direct update on the table, I'm creating a procedure which will update and commit 10000 rows at a time.

Given this, I have the following questions:

- What is the best way to carry out the update here? - as far as I can tell, the cursor allows iteration over 1 row at a time. Is updating 10000 rows one at a time, then committing, and repeating until the table is updated the correct way to do it?
- Is there any better way to handle the original issue of changing the data type of a column in a simpler way?

Comment: No need for a stored procedure, have pk conditions instead to update 10000 rows at the time.

Comment: @jarlh Wont I need to loop and stop at some point? How do I do that without a procedure?

Comment: What Db2 version and platform? What data types? You can change some of the data types. And there is ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE to change incompatible types. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html

Comment: @data_henrik db2 10.5 LUW, changing from varchar to clob.

Comment: If the average row-length is also changing significantly , there may be a follow-on impact on the pagesize, so consider carefully if tablespace changes will also be necessary. CLOB columns also have restrictions on how they are used in SQL, and you may also get impacts at application-code lever due to the way large objects are handled.  Be very careful with your impact assessment before you make this change.

Comment: Create a new table with the desired definition and do a `LOAD FROM CURSOR`.

Comment: @mustaccio i tried load from cursor for my case and it does work, thanks. Would you add it as an answer with an example?

Comment: You can probably answer your own question, since you already have a working example handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 has a feature called LOAD FROM CURSOR that allows for fast migration of data.

The following is an example of this using LOAD FROM CURSOR:

```
-- this is the original table
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TEXT VARCHAR(50)
)@

CREATE TABLE TEST_NEW (
    ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TEXT CLOB(5000000)
)@

DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TEST@

LOAD FROM C1 OF CURSOR INSERT INTO TEST_NEW (ID,TEXT)@ 

DROP TABLE TEST@
RENAME TABLE TEST_NEW TO TEST@
```

In addition, the following procedure can also be used (commit after every 10000 records):

```
-- this is the original table
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TEXT VARCHAR(50)
)@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MIGRATE_TEST()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN

    DECLARE EOF INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE CUR_COUNT INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CUR_ID INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE C CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
        SELECT ID FROM TEST WHERE TEXT_NEW IS NULL;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        SET EOF = 1;

    OPEN C;

    FETCH_LOOP: LOOP
        FETCH FROM C INTO CUR_ID; 
        IF EOF <> 0 THEN
                LEAVE FETCH_LOOP;
        END IF;

        UPDATE TEST 
        SET TEXT_NEW = TEXT
        WHERE ID = CUR_ID ;

        SET CUR_COUNT = CUR_COUNT + 1;

        IF CUR_COUNT >= 10000 THEN
            CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COMMITTING');
            COMMIT WORK;
            SET CUR_COUNT = 0;
        END IF;

    END LOOP FETCH_LOOP;

    COMMIT WORK;

    CLOSE C;
END@
```